# How anti-inflammatory are nsaids?

Tags: medications, pain

So I currently have some bad tonsillitis and an infection in one of my ears. My doctor at school gave me ibuprofen (for pain and anti-inflammation) and penicillin. I was just wondering if higher doses (doc told me 2x 200mg tablets) would reduce inflammation even further. Is there a point where the nsaid can't help anymore, even in higher doses? (Ex. If I take 3 200mg pills will it reduce inflammation even more than 2 pills would?)

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). I'm not sure that this is on topic (personal medical advice isn't), but I,m not going to vote to close just yet. In general, it is unwise to ignore your doctor's advice **especially** regarding the increase of a dose. Such a large increase should not be done by yourself or by following advice on the internet. You can read the patient information leaflet that comes with the medicine, and look at the section *adverse effects*.

Comment: @Lucky - This walks a fine line, I'll agree. Without the personal details, the basic question is "If X dose reduces inflammation, would X*2 dose reduce it even further?" which is on topic. But, the intent behind it makes it personal. As with you, I will wait (Since my close vote is like a presidential veto :p)

Answer (score 3):

You're asking if there is a dose response relationship for ibuprofen, and what does it look like. For most people the analgesic effect (surrogate for inflammation) flattens out at 400 mg, but 20% might get a better response with a higher dose. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2000723/

Comment: Good answer. It's also important to point out that while higher doses could have incremental benefit, they may also cause adverse effects. Taking more than 400 mg of ibuprofen at a time may not be safe for certain individuals, including the elderly, people with high blood pressure, or people with kidney disease.

Comment: We routinely use 1600 mg of slow release Ibuprofen for arthritis patients.

Comment: As I'm sure you're aware, those slow release tablets will have different pharmacokinetics vs. the regular ones; higher doses can be tolerated because the compound is released over a longer period of time. In general, 3200 mg / 24h is the maximal safe dosage of ibuprofen for healthy adults. The maximal safe dosage would be much less in children or in people with comorbid disease.

Comment: Sure, I was just pointing out that drugs can be formulated in different ways to reduce the toxicity.